# what is the "class" parameter in structure()?

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `structure()` function to create a data frame in R.
I saw something like this

```
structure(mydataframe, class="data.frame")
```

Where did class come from?  I saw someone using it, but it is not listed in the R document.

Is this something programmers learned in another language and carries it over?  And it works.  I am very confused.

Edit: I realized dput(), is what actually created a data frame looking like this.  I got it figured out, cheers!

Comment: Why are you using `structure` to create a `data.frame`?

Comment: I strongly discourage you from creating a data.frame in this manner unless you know _exactly_ what you're doing.  You will likely create an ill-formed data.frame that will cause hard-to-find errors later in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably saw someone using `dput`. `dput` is used to post (usually short) data. But normally you would not create a data frame like that. You would normally create it with the `data.frame` function. See below

```
> example_df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(3),y=rnorm(3))
> example_df
           x          y
1  0.2411880  0.6660809
2 -0.5222567 -0.2512656
3  0.3824853 -1.8420050
> dput(example_df)
structure(list(x = c(0.241188014013708, -0.522256746461544, 0.382485333260912
), y = c(0.666080872170054, -0.251265630627216, -1.84200501106852
)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then, if someone wants to "copy" your `data.frame`, he just has to run the following:

```
> copied_df <- structure(list(x = c(0.241188014013708, -0.522256746461544, 0.382485333260912
+     ), y = c(0.666080872170054, -0.251265630627216, -1.84200501106852
+     )), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I put "copy" in quotes because note the following:

```
> identical(example_df,copied_df)
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(example_df,copied_df)
[1] TRUE
```

`identical` yields false because when you post your `dput` output, often the numbers get rounded to a certain decimal point.

Answer (score 4):

'class' is not a specific argument to the `structure` function - that's why you didn't find it in the help file.

`structure` takes an object and then any number of name/value pairs and sets them as attributes on the object. In this case, `class` was such an attribute. You can try this to add fictional 'foo' and 'bar' attributes to a vector:

```
x <- structure(1:3, foo=42, bar='hello')
attributes(x)
#$foo
#[1] 42
#
#$bar
#[1] "hello"
```

And as Joshua Ulrich and Xu Wang mentioned, you should not create a `data.frame` like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm scratching my head, wondering what "R Document" would not have said something about "class". It's a very basic component of the the language and how functions get applied. You should type this and read:

```
?class
?methods
```

Comment: It doesn't, (nor does it discuss `data.frame` or `list `or `row.names`) but it does link to help(attr) which mentions `class` as a typical attribute and provides a link to the `class` function. Help pages cannot be expected to be a whole book, and it hardly seems fair to criticize one that provided the sought after information within two clicks.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  But, you have to click right sublink, and then sublink again, to figure class() is actually there.  Even for experts, this can be confusing and tedious work.

Anyways, I got the problem sloved, see my edit.